# Java's Robot.createScreenCapture method taking longer on one machine

Tags: java, graphics, screenshot

I am using Java's Robot class to capture small sized screenshots. On machine1, with GTX460, I can take screenshots within 33ms but on another machine with same processor, but with GTX630, it takes over 45ms. 
Both machines are in 16bit monitor mode.

Any pointers on what could be going wrong ? I have checked Graphic card settings and all looks the same between the two machines.
Here is the call that I am using

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage myImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
```

Thanks.

Comment: How many times have you performed this test? Can you be sure both machines were in exactly the same state?

Comment: How much of a problem is this 12ms difference? Is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: I have performed this test so far over 50 times. I must say though, that sometimes I do get 33ms interval on machine2 (gtx630) but then it again increases with no code changes. 12ms is a big impact in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the moniter sizes are diffrent, there would be more pixels to capture and write to the buffered image.

Comment: The resolution of both monitors are set to same 1280x1024 so monitor size should not matter ?

Comment: if the monitor size was the same then I suppose that certainly isn't the issue.

Comment: XD well I think that's all the help I can give you, i'm quite the amateur still with Java and programming, that was my one shot at an answer, sorry :P